# How to unbind an event while jump to other page in NUXTjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have written this code in one page. It works but how can I unbind this event when i Jump to other page？

```js
 private mounted () {
      if (process.browser) {
        const banner:any = document.querySelector('.banner img')
        document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
          const offsetTop = window.scrollY
          const INTOR_HEIGHT = document.querySelector('.intro-text').offsetHeight
          if (offsetTop < INTOR_HEIGHT) {
            banner.style.top = offsetTop + 'px'
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

when I jump to other page form this page,this error is thrown:

> javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetHeight' of
>   null
>       at HTMLDocument.eval

Answer (score 0):

haha , VUE.js Instance Lifecycle Hooks also can use in nuxt.js.
so just like this

```js
private smoothSlier () {
      const banner:any = document.querySelector('.banner img')
      const offsetTop = window.scrollY
      const INTOR_HEIGHT:any = document.querySelector('.intro-text').offsetHeight
      if (offsetTop < INTOR_HEIGHT) {
        banner.style.top = offsetTop + 'px'
      }
    }
private mounted () {
      if (process.browser) {
        document.addEventListener('scroll', this.smoothSlier)
      }
    }

    private beforeDestroy () {
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', this.smoothSlier)
    }
```

the point is bind golbal event in mounted hooks and,unbind in beforeDestroy